# JQuery Mobile ui-datepicker theme

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to change the ui-datepicker theme to "a" but it doesn't seem to inherit it.

Does anyone know how to change the theme for the datepicker please?

Thanks

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/10/28/announcing-themeroller-for-mobile-beta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jayraj mentioned, the datepicker for jQueryMobile is still in an experimentation phase, but I've had a moderate amount of success in manually changing the layout themes set by default in the jQueryMobile datepicker widget (jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js).

The following elements are giving a default data-theme of **'c'** (through their class names) :

```
$( ".ui-datepicker-calendar th", dp ).addClass("ui-bar-c");
$( ".ui-datepicker-calendar td", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c");
```

As well as the following style for a ui-btn-up widget with a data-theme of **'e'**:

```
$( ".ui-datepicker-calendar a.ui-state-highlight", dp ).addClass("ui-btn-up-e");
```

Changing these values to

```
ui-bar-a 
ui-body-a
ui-btn-up-c
```

respectfully have yielded expected results, but I would imagine that making these values dynamic by changing them based on the options passed in would be a much better solution :3

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Mobile CSS file does not contain any classes for ui-datepicker or anything similar. The datepicker is also given as experimental on the jQuery Mobile documentation site. It probably isn't possible right now